# Firebase: Store anonymous authentication in cookies

Tags: javascript, cookies, firebase, anonymous

I am developing multi page application, that uses firebase as a back-end.
On every page after firebase initialization I have the following code:

```
firebase.auth().signInAnonymously().catch(...);

firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged(function(user) 
{
    if (user) {
        // ...
    } else {
        // User is signed out.
        // ...
    }
    // ...
});
```

which sign in every visitor anonymously.

The problem is, when user navigates to another page of my application or opens it in a new tab, or just refreshes the current page - new anonymous user is generated.

I can use client side cookies to store anonymous user id, but how can I later (after page refresh) use that stored anonymous user id, to sign in user with that id?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It was my mistake,
firebase store anonymous user authorization in local storage by default.

My code sample should be rewritten this way to work properly:

```
firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged(function(user) 
{
    if (user) {
        // User is signed in
        // ...
    } else {
        // User is signed out.
        firebase.auth().signInAnonymously().catch(/*...*/);
    }
    // ...
});
```